# How do I install a package outside of the APT database?

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Linux, so this might sound like a simple question, but how do I install a package outside of the APT database? I am trying to install the following package:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdb2pqr

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of the APT database"?

Comment: Please provide OS & release details, the package is available for most on-topic releases as far as I can see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=pdb2pqr

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  `pdb2pqr` is in the `universe` repository. You should be able to install it using `apt` or the GUI package manager.  Can you edit your question and include more details about the problem you are experiencing?

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume you are currently running Huriste Hippo (21.04).

1. Expand "[The Hirsute Hippo (current stable release)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdb2pqr)" section.

   You will see a list of Package files.
2. Select and download the the `*.deb` (`*.ddeb`) files for your architecture.

   For AMD64, you would pick:

   - [pdb2pqr-dbgsym_2.1.1+dfsg-7build1_amd64.ddeb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/pdb2pqr-dbgsym_2.1.1+dfsg-7build1_amd64.ddeb) - Debug symbols for pdb2pqr. Note, this is probably optional, unless you need to debug the software.
   - [pdb2pqr_2.1.1+dfsg-7build1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/pdb2pqr_2.1.1+dfsg-7build1_amd64.deb) - Preparation of protein structures for electrostatics calculations
   - [pdb2pqr-doc_2.1.1+dfsg-7build1_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/pdb2pqr-doc_2.1.1+dfsg-7build1_all.deb) - Example files accompanying pdb2pqr
3. Open a terminal and execute the following commands.

   Let's assume you downloaded these files to your Downloads directory.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
4. Add the universe repository so Ubuntu can download other dependent packages you may need. Also this is needed for the `gdebi` command below.

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository universe
   sudo apt update
   ```
5. Install `gdebi`, a tool to allow you to install `*.deb` files and automatically install their dependencies.

   ```
   sudo apt install gdebi-core
   ```
6. Install your downloaded packages.

   ```
   sudo gdebi pdb2pqr_2.1.1+dfsg-7build1_amd64.deb
   sudo gdebi pdb2pqr-doc_2.1.1+dfsg-7build1_all.deb
   sudo gdebi pdb2pqr-dbgsym_2.1.1+dfsg-7build1_amd64.ddeb
   ```

Comment: Please do not invent new unique rectangular wheels! https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/pdb2pqr

Comment: @N0rbert, that's my interpretation of "outside of the APT database". You should post the traditional technique as an answer, especially if the OP is simply looking to install the recommended version of `pdb2pqr` and not download an older/newer/development deb file to install manually?