# How does sources.list for Hirsute Hippo (21.04) looks like?

Tags: software-sources, 21.04

Please can somebody post here the sources.list for Hirsute Hippo ?

I know this depends on internet connection (WLAN or Cable?).

This might be then different.

Am interested in differences of data-connections.

Comment: is [this resource](https://linuxhint.com/sources_list_ubuntu/) helpful?

Comment: Can you please tell us why you ask? Is the sources.list on your installation defective? sources.list should be pretty standard, unless you've added more repositories or PPAs. I also don't see a bounty on your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443036/what-is-the-correct-output-of-cat-etc-apt-sources-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: sources.list is not dependent on your data connection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 21.04 _Hirsute Hippo_ - Release amd64 (20210420)]/ hirsute main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Comment: hello - my idea was to have two different sources.lists - here is running xubuntu and I want to make it fit for hippo. Yes it is 32 bit but, when there is 64 bit then simply the right side of address field is zeroed out. So it would work then with hippo too ? With two different sources.list I thought I could write little bash script for this to choose between both with OR and then to merge the updates together - but not forced, simply as option of choosing with OR ? is this possible ?

Comment: @dschinn1001 I have no idea what you're trying to do. You asked that somebody post the sources.list for 21.04, and that's what I did.

Answer (score 6):

If you are running Hirsute, you can get an example of the default `sources.list` as follows:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list
```

This is the same for all installs, so it does not depend on "data-connections".

If you are looking for additional repositories listed in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, this is empty for a default install.

Comment: @mook765, good catch! Thanks.

Comment: Again, this file will fail, it does not contain *universe* and *multiverse* pockets. So it is useless IRL.

Comment: @N0rbert, I think you are referring to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339447/how-do-i-install-a-package-outside-of-the-apt-database/1339455#1339455). Notice that the universe repository is added in step 4 of that answer, because it was necessary for that answer. In this case, the user asked for the `sources.list` for Hirsute Hippo. I may be mistaken, but I believe the original file after a fresh install does not have universe or multiverse enabled by default, so the user has to add them afterwards, if they want.

Comment: Correct source.list file installed from desktop ISO contain *universe* and *multiverse*, they are enabled out the box. That is why I'm criticizing the used file.

Comment: @N0rbert - you can edit the network-manager file like follows : Edit the release upgrader. Open and edit the /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades file and ensure that the Prompt variable is set to normal. With 'Prompt=normal'